# How to loop through an array of nested object and remove the outer keys, and just leave the rest of the object in Nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Javascript and Nodejs and I can't figure out how to loop through the below array of objects and remove its numerical keys. So that when I extract the keys of each object in the array I get -
`['City', 'Operator Name', 'Operator Id', 'Transaction Type']` for each object.

An array of nested objects is given in this format

```
[
  {
    '0': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'GEORGE KUTTY K',
      'Operator Id': 1808,
      Amount: 3200,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '1': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SAJI VARGHESE',
      'Operator Id': 1723,
      Amount: 276.512,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '2': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SUNEESH K D',
      'Operator Id': 1010,
      Amount: 600,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '3': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'PRASAD TK',
      'Operator Id': 1745,
      Amount: 19.8,
      'Transaction Type': 'Paid'
    }
  }
]
```

I need the keys of each object  - `['City', 'Operator Name', 'Operator Id', 'Transaction Type']`

Comment: The second format is not a valid JS object

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks for pointing that out. I need to loop through the original array of Objects and get back the keys - ['City', 'Operator Name', 'Operator Id', 'Transaction Type'] for each object. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `Object.keys(element)` for each element of the original object.

Comment: You just want the keys or do you want to move the objects up to the array level? What is the end result? an array of keys or an array of objects?

Comment: WHy isn't `Amount` in your result?

Comment: What is the full result for all the array elements supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this - an array of objects. Look carefully at yours, it's an invalid data type, if you have braces { } you're declaring an object that needs a key with the value.

```
[
    {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'GEORGE KUTTY K',
      'Operator Id': 1808,
      Amount: 3200,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SAJI VARGHESE',
      'Operator Id': 1723,
      Amount: 276.512,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SUNEESH K D',
      'Operator Id': 1010,
      Amount: 600,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'PRASAD TK',
      'Operator Id': 1745,
      Amount: 19.8,
      'Transaction Type': 'Paid'
    }
]
```

As for the solution

```
let array =
[
  {
    '0': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'GEORGE KUTTY K',
      'Operator Id': 1808,
      Amount: 3200,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '1': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SAJI VARGHESE',
      'Operator Id': 1723,
      Amount: 276.512,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '2': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SUNEESH K D',
      'Operator Id': 1010,
      Amount: 600,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
    },
    '3': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'PRASAD TK',
      'Operator Id': 1745,
      Amount: 19.8,
      'Transaction Type': 'Paid'
    }
  }
]

console.log(array); //this is your starting array, notice it just has one object in there at index 0

let arrayTransform = []; //this is where we will store our result

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(array[0])){
  console.log(key,value);
  arrayTransform.push(value);
}

console.log('array transform looks like', arrayTransform);

//arrayTransform should look like this
//[
//   {
//     City: 'Kottayam',
//     'Operator Name': 'GEORGE KUTTY K',
//     'Operator Id': 1808,
//     Amount: 3200,
//     'Transaction Type': 'Received'
//   },
//   {
//     City: 'Kottayam',
//     'Operator Name': 'SAJI VARGHESE',
//     'Operator Id': 1723,
//     Amount: 276.512,
//     'Transaction Type': 'Received'
//   },
//   {
//     City: 'Kottayam',
//     'Operator Name': 'SUNEESH K D',
//     'Operator Id': 1010,
//     Amount: 600,
//     'Transaction Type': 'Received'
//   },
//   {
//     City: 'Kottayam',
//     'Operator Name': 'PRASAD TK',
//     'Operator Id': 1745,
//     Amount: 19.8,
//     'Transaction Type': 'Paid'
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're trying to do

```js
let oldArr = [
  {
    '0': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'GEORGE KUTTY K',
      'Operator Id': 1808,
      Amount: 3200,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
      }
  },
    {'1': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SAJI VARGHESE',
      'Operator Id': 1723,
      Amount: 276.512,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
      }
   },
    {'2': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'SUNEESH K D',
      'Operator Id': 1010,
      Amount: 600,
      'Transaction Type': 'Received'
      }
    },
    {'3': {
      City: 'Kottayam',
      'Operator Name': 'PRASAD TK',
      'Operator Id': 1745,
      Amount: 19.8,
      'Transaction Type': 'Paid'
    }
  }
]
let newArr = [];

oldArr.forEach(obj => newArr.push(...Object.values(obj)))

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Your old array doesn't look like the input array in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The format mentioned below is wrong here and even with your correction, doesn't make sense that much but I'll try to help.
What I can understand is you are trying to extract the ***values*** of the given objects the the array here, what you can do is use `Object.values()` operator [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). So we can do two things here if you just want the keys you can do `Object.keys()` which will give you this

```
Array(4) [ "0", "1", "2", "3" ]
```

And if you want to extract the values and keep it into Array format you can do `Object.values()` which will give you the output here

```
[{ City: "Kottayam", "Operator Name": "GEORGE KUTTY K", "Operator Id": 1808, … },
​{ City: "Kottayam", "Operator Name": "SAJI VARGHESE", "Operator Id": 1723, … },
{ City: "Kottayam", "Operator Name": "SUNEESH K D", "Operator Id": 1010, … },
{ City: "Kottayam", "Operator Name": "PRASAD TK", "Operator Id": 1745, … }]
```

And if you want these values wrapped around in another Object instead of Array just do this `const obj={...array}`
I hope this helps, please uptick and mark the answer as correct if it helps